# Interface can never instantiate in java,But What happened,when Interface is used return type

Tags: java, jdbc, interface, instance

We know,interface can never instantiate in java. We can, however, refer to an object that implements an interface by the type of the interface

```
public interface A
{
}
public class B implements A
{
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    A test = new B();  //upcating
    //A test = new A(); // wont compile
}
```

But I have become confused when interface is used return type,such as

> Method of DriverManager class which return Connection object
>   public static Connection getConnection(String url);

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(String url);
```

Same problem

> Method of Connection interface which return Statement object
>   public Statement createStatement();

```
Statement stat=con.createStatement();
```

I cannot understand,what happened when interface is used return type.
Please help me by explain.

Thanks

Comment: what is it that you are confused about?

Comment: Same as in 'upcasting' case.

Comment: You seem to understand that you can upcast, so what do you have trouble about in the example `public A getA() { return new B(); }`

Comment: @clctoThanks a lot,I am beginner in java,I can understand clearly.before i think how is it possible.

Comment: " interface is used return type." it mean a reference to an object which implements that interface is returned (or null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an interface is used as the return type of a method, what is actually being returned is an instance of a class that implements that interface.

Answer (score 0):

The returned object is than a subclass which implements said interface.

**Test classes**

```
public interface Printable {
    public String print();
}
public class A implements Printable {
    public String print() { return "I am A"; }
}
public class B implements Printable {
    public String print() { return "I am B"; }
}
```

**Example code**

```
private static final A a = new A();
private static final B b = new B();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random(0);
    System.out.println(getA().print());
    System.out.println(getB().print());
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        System.out.println(getAorB(random).print());
}

public static Printable getA() {
    return a;
}

public static Printable getB() {
    return b;
}

public static Printable getAorB(Random random) {
    return random.nextBoolean() ? a : b;
}
```

**Output**

```
I am A
I am B
I am A
I am A
I am B
I am A
I am A
```